# C# Error Handling in a series of calls

Tags: c#, error-handling

So completely new to Err handling, but trying to understand.

For a single process, I have this :

```
try
{
     myGetDataFunction();
}catch(SqlException ex){
     myLogExceptionRoutine();
}catch{
     throw;
}
```

My next step is to look at situation where I have multiple sequential calls.
E.g.

```
public void foo(){
    callA();
    callB();
}
```

I do not want callB to be called, if callA fails.
Question is, do I just wrap both A & B in a single try/catch, or do I a separate try/catch for each ?
.. and withing that, I am trying to understand the 'why' about it all.

So like this ?

```
try{
    callA();
    callB();
}catch{
     // handling stuff
}
```

or like this bizarre psuedo code, which just does not look 'right' ?

```
try{
   callA();
}catch{
   // handle error
}
if(somevalidityCheck){
    try{
       callB();
    }catch{
       // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `catch { throw: }`.

Comment: you just need to put callA() and callB() in a single try. if A is failed, B will not be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an exception occurs within a `try` block the rest of the `try` block is skipped so your code

```
try
{
    callA();
    callB();
}
catch{}
```

would not execute `callB` if `callA` raises an exception.  The only reason to split this up into two `try-catch` blocks would be if you needed to handle the exceptions differently and in that case you can nest the blocks to maintain the behavior of `callB` being skipped when `callA` throws.

```
try
{
    callA();
    try
    {
        callB();
    }
    catch 
    {
        Debug.Log("callB raised exception");
    }
}
catch
{
    Debug.Log("callA raised exception and callB was not executed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  It's always good to know when something doesn't just work - but is also the 'right' way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

First of write it in C# standard brackets with the { } on new lines by themselves. :) No java here!!

You example is a perfectly acceptible way to write your exceptions assuming it is able to do what you want.

```
try
{
    callA();
    callB();
}
catch
{
     // Handle A or B exception. Do you need to know specific details about what A or B is doing?
}
```

If you need further details about the exception for logging then it can be useful to catch the exception in CallA or B, log the necessary details and then throw the exception.

Code would get very messy very fast if everyone wrapped every method in a try/catch.